# How to use the object sent with the --data-binary option in curl to create an image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, parse-platform, carrierwave

If I have, for example, this curl command:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" \
  --data-binary '@myPicture.jpg' \
  https://localhost:3000/1/files/pic.jpg
```

I'm building an API (like the one from parse.com). This request is for uploading picture. I want to fetch the picture with the --data-binary option. With **request.body** I get something like **StringIO:0x00000004634648**. With **request.body.open** I get a bunch of random characters (I guees that the binary file). How can I use this to upload the picture. With **carrierwave** or **paperclip** I need the **path** of the image but I don't get the path here. I don't want to change the curl command 'cause I want the exactly same command as on Parse API. Any idea?

Comment: I had similar issue. I added following settings to the curl 1. `-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'` 2. `-F "content[image]=@PATH_TO_FILE/picture.png;type=image/png"`. And I managed to accept file with paperclip. maybe it helps you

Answer (score 1):

The answer is apsurd. Paperclip allows this:

```
newimage = Photo.new
newimage.image = request.body
newimage.save
```

request.body is a StringIO.

Answer (score 0):

when you upload image from api(json) you will get hashie mash, you need to convert them to ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile. You can do it like:-

```
def initialize(user, params)
  @user = user
  @params = params
end

def process
  @params[:avatar] = parse_image_data(@params[:avatar]) if @params[:avatar]
  @user.update!(@params)
ensure
  clean_tempfile
end

private

def parse_image_data(image_data)
  @tempfile = Tempfile.new('user-avatar')
  @tempfile.binmode
  @tempfile.write Base64.decode64(image_data[:file_data])
  @tempfile.rewind

  ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
    :tempfile => @tempfile,
    :content_type => image_data[:content_type],
    :filename => image_data[:filename]
  )
end

def clean_tempfile
  if @tempfile
    @tempfile.close
    @tempfile.unlink
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this. Params are a Hashie::Mash object, but it looks like: #<Hashie::Mash file_name="pic" format="jpg" route_info=#<Grape::Route:0x00000003767840 @options={:prefix=>nil, :version=>"1", :namespace=>"/files", :method=>"POST", :path=>"/:version/files/:file_name(.:format)", :params=>{"file_name"=>""}, :compiled=>/\A\/(?<version>1)\/files\/(?<file_name>[^\/.?]+)(?:\.(?<format>[^\/.?]+))?\Z/}>>  No image here. The image is in **request.body**. And the result is StringIO:0x0...